# Displaying result of query

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am trying to display the data in the `datagridview` in windows form.

I have following code to fetch data from the database.

```
    public DataSet GetUser(string custName)
    {
        string connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\Amrit\\Desktop\\Database.accdb ;Persist Security Info=False;";
        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
        OleDbConnection oleConn = new OleDbConnection(connString);

        try
        {
            oleConn.Open();
            string sql = "SELECT * FROM [Customer] WHERE [Customer's Ebayname]=" + custName;
            OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, oleConn);
            dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet, "Customer");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            oleConn.Close();
        }
        if (dataSet.Tables.Count <= 0)
            return null;
        else
            return dataSet;
    }
```

Above I am passing the value of `custName` from the `textBox` in the windows form. This will display all the rows containing that name.

Here, how I am trying to display the data.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataSet ds = GetUser(textBox1.Text);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
    }
```

Can somebody point out where I am wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about return the Function as `DataTable`?

```
public DataTable GetUser(string custName)
{
   //..codes
   return dataSet.Tables["Customer"];
}
```

and I suspect this is your problem

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM [Customer] WHERE [Customer's Ebayname]=" + custName;
```

notice that the `custName` the `DataType` is `Text` and your `Where clause` something's not right so its should be like

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM [Customer] WHERE Ebayname = '" + custName + "'";
```

***P.S.**: Don't forget to follow the advice of Mr. Steve*

Comment: what do you mean mr. steve?

Comment: If custName contains a single quote the sql is invalid and you get a syntax error. Do not SUGGEST to use string concatenation. NEVER.

Comment: if you mean about the single quote.. then try it, i just looking straight about OP's problem. sometimes OPs not concerned about the `Parameters` because that's the way their teacher teaches on how to manipulating the data(if am correct) they teach as simple as they can. i hope you understand. `:D`

Comment: No, I don't understand how it is possible to 'teach' a very bad practice and why to perpetuate the error on a website that is supposed to give correct answers. Question closed for me.

Comment: yes i know that.. why I mentioned your name in my answer because for that matter of  `sql injection`. about the __bad practice__ some teacher are not so expert to teach _or_ concerned about `sql injection`.. so that is why every day like this question is appear has no `parameters` i hope you get what i mean `:)`

Answer (score 2):

First you need to check if your Dataset contains any result for you command. Then do not use string concatenation in that way to build command, but always parametrized queries. This will allow to avoid [Sql Injections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/xkcd-sql-injection-please-explain) and parsing problems on string, dates and numeric decimals.

Have you tried what happens when your custName variable contains a single quote?

```
....
using(OleDbConnection oleConn = new OleDbConnection(connString))
{
    try
    {
        oleConn.Open();
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM [Customer] WHERE [Customer's Ebayname]=@cust";
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, oleConn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cust", custName);
        OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet, "Customer");
    }
}
....
```

Answer (score 1):

Bind your `DataGirdView` to `DataTable` returned.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataSet ds = GetUser(textBox1.Text);
    if (ds == null)
    {
         return;
    }
    dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["Customer"];
}
```

Comment: i have already tried that and its throwing me null reference exception

Comment: when i put break point at dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["Customer"];, it doesnot get hit, even though the value i enter exist in database