# Displaying data in console window from database

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2012

I created this simple 'Employee' program to train up my sql.
And I decided to show all the data from the database if the user want to.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace MySQLQueryTest
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string response = "";
        while (response != "exit")
        {
            Console.Write(">>");
            response = Console.ReadLine();
            switch (response.ToLower())
            {
                case "emp":
                    employeeMenu();
                    break;
                case "-h":
                    Console.WriteLine("emp\tDisplays the Employee database menu");
                    Console.WriteLine("exit\tWill exit the program");
                    Console.WriteLine("clear\tWill clear the console window");
                    break;
                case "clear":
                    Console.Clear();
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid Command; for help type -h");
                    break;

            }
        }
    }
    static void employeeMenu()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("-------------Menu-------------");
        Console.WriteLine("Type 'list' to list all employees.");
        Console.WriteLine("Type 'add' to add an employee.");
        Console.WriteLine("------------------------------");
        string response = "";
        while (response != "exit")
        {
            Console.Write("EmployeeMenu>");
            response = Console.ReadLine();
            switch (response.ToLower())
            {
                case "add":
                    getInfo();
                    break;
                case "exit":
                    Console.WriteLine("Returning to Main Menu...");
                    break;
                case "list":
                    Console.WriteLine("Here I will display all the SQL data");
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid Command\n");

                    break;
            }
        }

    }
    static void getInfo()
    {
        Console.Write("First Name: ");
        string fname = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Last Name: ");
        string lname = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Job: ");
        string job = Console.ReadLine();
        addEmployee(fname, lname, job);
    }
    static void addEmployee(string the_fname, string the_lname, string the_job)
    {
        var connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename='c:\users\omri\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Map\Map\db.mdf';Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand cmd;
        connection.Open();

        try
        {
            cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Employees(fname, lname, job) values('" + the_fname + "', '" + the_lname + "', '" + the_job + "');";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            Console.WriteLine("Added " + the_fname + " " + the_lname + " to employee database.");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

I was searching the internet for some answers, but no success, the closest thing I found was this: [Displaying result of query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14857369/displaying-result-of-query) .

Not sure this is what i'm looking for. 
So, my question is how can I show all the Data from Employees?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: there are countless examples of selecting data from a database. In terms of teaching yourself SQL you didn't get very far ! Good `SQLDataReader` and go from there. Also, look at your insert code and think about how you would extract instead of insert data ...

Comment: Read all data from data base into a datatable and display it...!!

Comment: I realize this is a simple app, but PLEASE read up on SQL injection, what it is and how to avoid it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Homework assignment?

You already have code that runs SQL queries when you are adding employees into your database. To show all the employees in your database you want to do something similar to your addEmployee method, but instead of running an INSERT sql command you want to SELECT

```
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(YOURCONNECTIONSTRING))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Employees", connection))
            {
                using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(reader.GetValue(i));
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```